# Pass C# object array to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I know there are a lot of great examples as to how to do this but I can't quite seem to get passing an array of objects from C# to javascript to work. I think I am really close because the array on the client side is receiving something, when I send 12 things, it prints out this:

```
"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

As you can see there are objects, and even 12 of them which means that it is getting sent (at least relatively) properly and stored in. I am just not sure how to parse the string into the objects and store them in the array. The code below is how I get the long string of objects above. Reading other examples I have tried parsing the string first with JSON but I can't get it right. Ex

```
var data;
var nodeEdges = JSON.parse(data);
```

Below is the code I am using that gets me the long list of '[object Object]'. Here is where I send it:

```
protected void VisualizeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Connection> Connections = new List<Connection>();  
            var x = from b in db.Connections where (b.VirusId == virusId) select b;
            Connections = x.ToList();
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Connections.ToList());
            ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("nodeEdges", json);
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page,Page.GetType(), "id","visualize('#visrep')", true);
        }
```

And here is my JS where I receive it (I am using D3.js).

```
var nodeEdges = [];
function visualize(element) {
    d3.select(element).selectAll("h2").data(nodeEdges).enter().append("h2").text(function (d) { return "We did it: " + d});
}
```

Probably don't need it but here is my object I am trying to send

```
public class Connection
{
    [Key]
    public int ConnectionId { get; set; }
    public int source { get; set; }
    public int destination { get; set; }
    public bool direct { get; set; }
    public string VirusId { get; set; }
    public Connection(int source_, int destination_, bool direct_, string virusId)
    {
        source = source_;
        destination = destination_;
        direct = direct_;
        VirusId = virusId;
    }
    public Connection()
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT**

I have broken down the issue into an even simpler example. My new C#

```
protected void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new testClass(66, 77));
    ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("data", json);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "id", "testFunc()", true);
}
```

My new javascript

```
var data;
function testFunc() {
    d3.select("#stuff").append("h2").text(data);
}
```

The serialized string is not being received into the 'data' var. When I step through the C# the serialized string is there and looks good but it just isn't showing up in the JS

My 'testClass' for those scientists out there

```
public class testClass
{
    public int target { get; set; }
    public int source { get; set; }
    public testClass(int t, int s)
    {
        target = t;
        source = s;
    }
    public testClass()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: In the click button event handler, is the json value being serialized properly from JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Connections.ToList());?

Comment: And as a side comment, why are you calling ConnectionslToList() again? It's already defined as a List<Connection>?

Comment: Oh woops. Thank you for pointing that out. I ran it again without that second .ToList(). No change.

Comment: You are asking about serialization. Specifically JSON serialization ([system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)).

Comment: Looking at the documentation for JsonConvert.SerializeObject, your usage appears to be correct. I am able to get the expected result using the System.Web.Script.Serialization in the following manner:


`string s = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(db.Connections.Where(x => x.VirusId == "Hello"));`


But I'm not sure where that deviates from your example!

Comment: [object Object] is what JS will output when you print out the value of an object.  It looks like you're printing out the array (as in you're getting a json array correctly on the client side), have you tried using the browser's debugger to inspect the array itself?  maybe data[0] or something?

Comment: @DUBYATOO the debugger has this line var data =  new Array({"target":66,"source":77}); in it. This is where my inexperience stops me. If that info is reaching the browser how do I access it?

Comment: nvm, I figured it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regards to the simplified problem in my above edit the solution was painfully obvious. All I had to do was change the JS function to the code below and I can access the array. Truly the definition of obvious.

```
var data;
function testFunc() {
    d3.select("#stuff").append("h2").text(data[0].source);
}
```